# Parse JSON without Brackets from Webpage in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, brackets

I need to get JSON data from [https://realtimebitcoin.info/stats/](https://realtimebitcoin.info/)
(By the way, the link might redirect you to only https://realtimebitcoin.info/ or https://realtimebitcoin.info If that happens, then just add stats/ or /stats/ at the end of the search box text).

Unfortunately, the author of this JSON document didn't bother to surround it with brackets, and the document can't even be parsed properly. I tried to forcefully surround it with "[]", but that only created a null object at the end, and it can still not be parsed. I mean that JSONException keeps being thrown. Here is the code:

```
private static class UpdateBitcoinData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {

            // URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/j5f6b");
            // URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/gfoa2");
            String data = "";
            URL url = new URL("https://realtimebitcoin.info/stats/");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }
            String fixed = "[" + data + "]";
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(fixed);
            for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(index);
                /* singleParsed =  "Name:" + JO.get("name") + "\n"+
                        "Password:" + JO.get("password") + "\n"+
                        "Contact:" + JO.get("contact") + "\n"+
                        "Country:" + JO.get("country") + "\n"; */
                BitcoinInformation.TEST = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("ticker"));

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            BitcoinInformation.TEST = e.getMessage();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }

}
```

Any solutions would be helpful!

Comment: `"the document can't even be parsed properly."` what are you talking about? i threw the JSON returned from the URL into https://jsonlint.com and it is valid JSON. It's not an array. That's why it's not wrapped in `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON endpoints such as these are very rarely, if-ever, hand-written, they are normally converted into JSON via a library from some sort of Object.

The provided link is a JSON object with attributes `ticker`, `totalbtc`, and `hashrate`.

With that in mind, the simplest way to parse JSON is with a JSONObject.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject( str );
```

Where `str` is a string containing the JSON. See more about how to use a `JSONObject` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String))

Comment: How would I get a nested value such as "buy"?

Comment: To parse data from the `JSONObject` you must use a combination of the `JSONObject`'s [public methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#public-methods_3).

In particular, you can ask the root `JSONObject` to return any nested object with the 
```.getJSONObject(String name)``` 
method, passing the key (name) of the nested-object as the argument. You can also ask the object to return primitive variables with a combination of the methods `getLong()`, `getString()`, etc.